# How do I reason about conditionals in Coq?

Tags: functional-programming, conditional-statements, coq, theorem-proving

I'm working through the `ListSet` module from the Coq standard library. I'm unsure how to reason about conditionals in a proof. For instance, I am having trouble with the following proof. Definitions are provided for context.

```
Fixpoint set_mem (x : A) (xs : set) : bool :=
match xs with
  | nil       => false
  | cons y ys =>
      match Aeq_dec x y with
        | left  _ => true
        | right _ => set_mem x ys
      end
end.

Definition set_In : A -> set -> Prop := In (A := A).

Lemma set_mem_correct1 : forall (x : A) (xs : set),
  set_mem x xs = true -> set_In x xs.
Proof. intros. induction xs.
  discriminate.
  simpl; destruct Aeq_dec with a x.
    intuition.
    simpl in H.
```

The current proof state includes the `inr` of `Aeq_dec` as a hypothesis. I have discarded the base case of induction and the inductive case where the `inl` of `Aeq_dec` is true.

```
  A : Type
  Aeq_dec : forall x y : A, {x = y} + {x <> y}
  x : A
  a : A
  xs : list A
  H : (if Aeq_dec x a then true else set_mem x xs) = true
  IHxs : set_mem x xs = true -> set_In x xs
  n : a <> x
  ============================
   a = x \/ set_In x xs
```

The only way for `H` to be true if `a <> x` is if `set_mem xs` is true. I should be able to apply the conditional in `H` to `a <> x` in order to obtain `set_mem xs`. However, I don't understand how to do this. How do I deal with, or decompose, or apply conditionals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?  (syntax may be buggy, no coqtop here atm)

```
destruct (Aeq_dec x a);
[ subst; elim (n eq_refl)
| right; apply (IHxs H)
].
```

(`if <foo>` is more or less the same as `match <foo> with`.  You'll have to reduce (`destruct`, `case`, ...)  such that the match can be decided (or for the `if`, things must reduce to either the first or the second constructor of whatever type you're using it with.)  Most of the time, you'll need the value that gets case-analyzed (though not here).  If you need it, do a `remember (<value>) as foo; destruct foo` instead of destructing directly.)

Comment: I believe I that I understand. The `tactic destruct (Aeq_dec)` destructs the sum inside `H`, generating two subgoals for the left and right branches of the sum. The first case generates contradictory hypotheses and is trivial; the second introduces the antecedent of the induction hypothesis. I didn't realize that I could destruct a sum nested inside a hypothesis. Thank you for pointing this out.